# don't understand threading model on forms

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to wrap my head around the threading model of Windows Forms apps, and failing. We have a class/module with a string array you add to, and it's clear one add is getting stepped on by other calls/threads.

So we put together a little test harness to try to duplicate it:

```
Friend Module ErrTest
    <ThreadStatic()> Friend ErrLog As String = ""
End Module
Public Class ErrLogTest
    Public Sub New(T As Integer)
        SyncLock ErrLog
            For I = 1 To 10
                ErrLog &= "Test " & T & " Count " & I & "; "
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
    Public Function GetError() As String
        Dim Ans As String = ErrLog
        Return Ans
    End Function
    Public Sub SetError()
        ErrLog = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's the code in my main form, which is a button and three labels:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim EL As ErrLogTest.ErrLogTest

    EL = New ErrLogTest.ErrLogTest(1)
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Label1.Text = EL.GetError
    EL.SetError()

    EL = New ErrLogTest.ErrLogTest(2)
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Label2.Text = EL.GetError
    EL.SetError()

    EL = New ErrLogTest.ErrLogTest(3)
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Label3.Text = EL.GetError
    EL.SetError()
End Sub
```

If you push the button once, you get three outputs in the three form labels. Yay! But if you push the button in the middle of the update, you get partial output, then it redraws with the output from two of the loops in a single field.

I've tried various combinations of ThreadStatic and Synclock in various locations to no avail. The example above has locks in the Add, but I've put them in and taken them out of the other methods to try to find a pattern, no luck.

Is this a threading problem? Or am I missing something incredibly obvious?

We don't have control over the programs calling our DLL, so we can't modify them. Whatever solution we use needs to be in our module.

Comment: Better look into tasks, if you have .NET 4.0+, you should like it more. Or even async/await concept, if you are on .NET 4.5. Off top of my head, you should NOT be using `Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: So Neo, can I assume this *is* a threading problem then?

Comment: Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() can cause unexpected things to happen. Multi-threading can also do that, if improperly handled. When put together, they unleash havoc to your brain! Try to create a reduced test case for your problem, something I can reproduce on my PC, then it should be easier to diagnose.

Comment: According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx): "Note that in addition to applying the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute to a field, you must also define it as a static field (in C#) or a Shared field (in Visual Basic)."  I'm not sure if a field in a VB `Module` is technically considered a `Shared` field, in this context.  It certainly acts like one, but as far as the compiler is concerned, that attribute may not apply in that case.  Have you tried making it a shared field in a class?

Comment: Hi Steven, I do NOT have a shared variable - Darren mentioned this below. Placing the shared variable in the class fixes the problem without any threading tags because then every call in the main form is talking to a separate string anyway. The key problem here *appears* to be that the string is in the *module* and can be called from multiple classes.

Comment: Are you actually Starting another Thread anywhere? I don't see any mechanism that does this in your example code...

Comment: I assumed that this was happening with the multiple button clicks?

Comment: Clicking Registers an event to fire (when the primary thread has time for it), normally code in CLICK would finish then next registered event would fire. Saying "DoEvents" tells forms to start processing next event, code effectively stops at that point in the original click routine and continues in all the next events registered until free time is found again. then your original click event continues. having multiple overlapping DoEvents is going to give you random outcomes almost. There is no multiple threads here at all.

Comment: Ok, following this… how does doEvents "stop" my code? And how do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a "String" in your Synclock.

Strings are create each time they are assigned, so your locking on a new object during each call to the routine.

Create a dummy object that is global and static like this...

```
Public Shared SyncRoot as new object
```

Also you need to wrap the Access to ErrLog EVERYWHERE you are accessing it. not just the one routine that is assigning to it.

```
Public Class ErrLogTest
Public Shared SyncRoot as new object
Public Sub New(T As Integer)
    SyncLock SyncRoot
        For I = 1 To 10
            ErrLog &= "Test " & T & " Count " & I & "; "
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Next
    End SyncLock
End Sub
Public Function GetError() As String
    SyncLock SyncRoot
        Dim Ans As String = ErrLog
        Return Ans
    end synclock
End Function
Public Sub SetError()
    SyncLock SyncRoot
        ErrLog = ""
    End Synclock
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry Darren, no joy. I get the same problem of the strings being mixed up. Note that you can't put a shared object in a module, is that perhaps the root cause of the problem here?

Comment: Further to that, I suspect this has something to do with scoping the module vs. the classes, but I don't really know what.

Comment: The shared Object is inside the class. If you declare an object inside a module it is shared, has the same scope basically. Generally avoid Module usage in VB except for the most basic global things, it's generally considered poor structure. Modules in VB do sort of act like a Static Class except it's accessible everywhere in your local project

Comment: Ok I think I see where you're going... but then what if we have multiple classes sharing the same object - in this case a common string? For instance, let's say I add ErrorLogTest2 that wants to insert into the shared object?

Comment: Access to the Constructor, GetError, and SetError should all be safe from any thread if you have a dedicated sington sync object (like "SyncRoot" in my example). This should be the case regardless of which version of the ErrLogTest object you use and from which thread you use it from.
That being said, it's not so normal to create multiple object instances that only access one shared item under item, normally you would do this with a static class hiding ErrLog inside it as "Private Shared".

Comment: To test this I placed SyncRoot and my string inside the ErrLogTest class, and removed the module completely. I then made a second class within the class, ErrLogTest2, sharing the same private string and SyncRoot variables. I replaced one of my calls to ErrLogTest with a call to ErrLogTest2. The strings are still being messed up.

Comment: "DoEvents" is going to allow the Main Program Thread to Overlap Calls to the Button Click if you click it rapidly. This is not multiple threads, it is one thread that is having the execution path altered in a somewhat random fashion.

Comment: But this is the behaviour of the application that is calling our DLL. Is there no way to solve this?

Comment: If you have another application calling methods in your DLL you are limited to enforce sequence the sequence of events in just the one method call of your DLL. If the outside application is calling your code over and over, at all different points, from multiple threads, You can prevent overlap inside one synclock block space. That prevents the overlap based on the object, but you cannot force the order of which synclock is entered into next. It is most likely linked to the sequence called from the application.

Comment: Ok I guess my confusion is this: I've added synch locks to the code. And I'm still seeing the same problem. So what is different about one app's doEvent's than multiple apps calling it? What *exactly* is doEvents doing that is making thread locking not work?

Comment: SyncLock on an object works, regardless of DoEvents. You have a sequence issue or something at a basic level your not understanding. I think your example is confusing you more than anything else. I ran what I think is what you have in code (using the part I posted) and it output exactly what I would expect.